# not complete assigning for all records in database

Tags: c#, sql

I want to compute the shortest path by computing the distance between school and student locations, here is my code, It works only for the first row in the database but I do not Know why! and there is no error while running but takes a lot of time!It seems like there is an infinity loop !!but I do not Know where is the error??!!
the value of counter is romper of students

Comment: Please add detail to your question about what you actually are trying to achieve... and what is the initial value of `counter`?

Comment: Take a look at the use of indexers like `[j + 1]`, and what exactly are you trying to do? Traveling salesman?

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, beginners ;) Funny.

> but takes a lot of time!It seems like there is an infinity loop

You do realize that common sense says that an infinite loop does not take a LOT of time, but INFINITE time? SO if that thing comes back after 15 minutes it is likely atotally crappy algorithm, but it is NOT an infinite loop. Infinite is not slow, it is STOP HERE NEVER EXIT.

Given that you run 2 loops on data we do not know and that you run statements that make zero sense, I Would suggest you get a tutorial on how to use the debugger and start - debugging. That is developer baseline info and if you do not learn it now, rather give up programming - there is no chance to write more complex code without regularly using a debuger.

For pure performane there are profilers. Again, unless you hate programming and do not want to make anyhting more than small samples - you WILL need to use a profiler more or less regularly. Sp ypi cam start dpomg so now.

I think you will find out that you do a LOT of SQL stuff. THat is a select / update every time - and as such it is very inefficient (unless it happens ot often, but hey, without the data, how should I know?). I doubt you have so many busses (like: more than a couple of millions), it may make more sense to pull the data into memory once and then not hit the database until your loop is ready. Any select will take some time, and if you do that a lot - welcome to performance hell.

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere!

Comment: @geedubb es. WHen I learned programming that generally started with reading some books and the documentation of the tools one used. Today it seems to start by copy/pasting stuff from the interent - stuff beyond one's understanding - and then wondering why nothing works and asking for help without ever learning. The profession has degenerated from professionalism to amateurs.

Comment: dear : geedubb, and @TomTom actually I've tried but it doesn't work,and I've posted my code but when no body helped me I edited my post and deleted my code.pleas if u can't help don't talk badly about people!! I've never ever coped any code!!